# How to throw another exception in Mono?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I try to wrap exception that thrown in **Mono** into another exception. I try to use **onErrorResume()** and **doOnError()** methods, but it does not help. How can I do it?

```
 return response
                .handle((responseData, sink) -> handleStatus(data, logContext, sink))
                .doOnError(v -> {
                    throw new CriticalException("str", "str", "str", "str", "str", "str");
                });
```

Comment: Yes, it is java

Comment: Ok, and why does it not work? Is `CriticalException` a checked exception?

Comment: "Why does it not work" means "What error do you see"?

Comment: No, it is unchecked

Comment: CriticalException doesn't throws, but I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally use `onErrorResume()`, resuming to a publisher that supplies your new error as so:

```
.onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new CriticalException()))
```